# How to create a new csv log file every time the current log file size exceeds 10 MB in Automation Anywhere?

Tags: csv, logic, logfile, automationanywhere

[image: The given block of code is only generating two log files and not third one onwards]

While unit testing its appending to the second file and not creating a third one

Answer (score 0):

You can use while condition like below.
"log-child" will prepare log file name based on size and counter at mentioned "logfolder" locaiton.
"log-parent" will call log-child in loop and we can see it created log files with mentioned size and keeps appending with new counter.

[image]